# Grow and shrink table height dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

I have a dialog box and its body is divided into three parts
- Body Title
- Table
- Footer

Within body I have two div's. Div1 for Body Title and, Div2 for Table and Footer.

```
.div2 {
    height: 88%;
}

.table{
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

When there is only one body title it works fine but if there are multiple body titles (multiple rows) then table and footer overflows the dialog body which I don't want.

I tried various combination of flex properties but could not get it right. (because of my limited flex knowledge).

Expected: Even if there are multiple rows for`Body Title`, `Table and Footer` should not overflow dialog body and adjust their height within available space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This much line of css can fixed your problem

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.body-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

As per your requirement I think your html code should be like this

```
<div class="body-wrapper">
  <div class="div1">
    <p>This is title</p>
  </div>  
  <div class="div2">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <footer>
      <p>This is footer</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With ` justify-content: space-between;` it gives lot of white space  between body title and table.

Comment: You can fixed with height the way i did height:100vh; you can make it 50,60 anything as per your design requirement.

Comment: Actually, I did not require `justify-content: space-between` and it works fine now. Thanks.